# Setting up a subclass for UIButton to handle look-and-feel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a AuthButtons.h header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AuthButtons : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIColor *backgroundColor;


@end
```

The implementation AuthButtons.m class is as follows:

```
#import "AuthButtons.h"

@implementation AuthButtons

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

- (UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    return [UIColor whiteColor];
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then in my viewcontroller.m class I have:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) AuthButtons *registerButton;


@end


...

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _registerButton = [AuthButtons buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [_registerButton setTitle:@"Register" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_registerButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    _registerButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.screenWidth / 2.0, 100.0);

    [_registerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

It keeps crashing when I try to create the button.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strong instead of weak(i always use strong type when using buttons in ARC enabled class,not sure whether its a bad habbit :-))

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AuthButtons *registerButton;
```

and add it as your subview(`[self.view addSubview:_registerButton]`).Hope you have implemeted the function called `-(void)buttonPressed:(id )sender` in your class.

Comment: still crashing on that line, something else must be going on

Comment: nm, i had a misplaced [ outside a comment

Comment: and from where did u get the buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem?..it has to be buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom..

Comment: how do i use the backgroundColor to set my buttons background color from the AuthButtons class?

Comment: -(void)setUrBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)urcolor; 

add this in your AuthButtons.h and implement 

-(void)setUrBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)urcolor
{
    self.backgroundColor=urcolor;
    
}
in your AuthButtons.m class

Comment: okay i see that, is there any way to do this in initWithFrame:  
        self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

Comment: I can't seem to get the AuthButtons class initWithFrame to create the button and then just set the text in my view controller, it crashes

Comment: Works fine when I create the button in the view controller tho

Answer (score 2):

Your button is weak and not added as a subview so its deallocated right away